# twitter bootstrap responsive website with fixed length and width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fixed-width, fixed-length-record

I have noticed several people providing good feedback on a fixed width for twitter bootstrap.  My problem is I need fixed width and LENGTH on my layout and it must be viewable on multiple platforms (Smarphone, ipad and multiple pc screen sizes).  We have taken a theme and tried to do a fixed design on length and width, but always need to adjust for various screen sizes.    Any idea on how we can adjust a design that allow everything to fit on one screen (no scrolling down or side ways) using a twitter bootstrap theme and not having to test multiple screen sizes?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't scroll and you need to allow for an arbitrary screen size, you need to either:

- Have very little content, or
- Zoom your content to fit.

The latter will require some annoying javascript, I think; it's really not what I would recommend.

Pick the smallest screen you want to support and make sure all of your pages fit on it without scrolling. Set your fixed width to the width of that screen. Heads up: it will look tiny and terrible on larger devices.

I'd still recommend testing on multiple devices.